# Getting an Error JsValue Expected but JsNode Supplied

Tags: scala, playframework

I am using Play 2.5 and I need advices on a compile error. It is saying that I have given JsNode value but JsValue expected. I don't know what is wrong.

```
  val response : Future[Result] =
    controller.foo()
      .apply(FakeRequest(POST, "/form")
        .withHeaders(CONTENT_TYPE -> JSON)
        .withJsonBody(Json.parse("""{"name":"Jacek","age":41}""")))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just checked your code:

```
  lazy val controller = inject[HomeController]

  controller.index()
      .apply(
  FakeRequest("POST", "/form")
    .withJsonBody(Json.parse("""{"name":"Jacek","age":41}""")))
```

This works.

So my guess is: **You have imported the wrong `Json` object.**

Make sure you imported: `play.api.libs.json.Json`